# How to setup smtp connection for symfony with mailer bundle?

Tags: symfony, smtp, mailer, dsn

I'm currently hosting my website in a shared server with a mail option. I want to send mail (ex: from support@domain.com) but I'm encountering an issue:

```
Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "(username)" using the following authenticators:
"LOGIN", "PLAIN". Authenticator "LOGIN" returned "Symfony\Component\Mailer\Exception\TransportException:
Expected response code "235" but got code "535", with message "535 5.7.8 Error: authentication failed: UGFzc3dvcmQ6". in
/home/(...)/vendor/symfony/mailer/Transport/Smtp/SmtpTransport.php:297
```

My MAILER_DSN is smtp://smtp://username:password@server:465, normally this is correct, so I don't see where the problem could come from.

Thanks !

Comment: `smtp://smtp://username:password@server:465` looks invalid.